# is there a way to save off css style info from a website?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to save off css style info from a website? For example, say you're having a weird css issue and you want to save off the style info from Chrome Dev Tools so you can save the style info with another developer for review. CDT can sometimes display a lot of info for "Styles" and "Computed" so it would be nice to be able to save this info off in a nice clean file format.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in Chrome Dev Tools and you see the CSS rule you can also click on the link above it to go to the file that CSS rule is in. If you right click on this link and select "open in new tab" you can download the whole CSS file.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-used/cdopjfddjlonogibjahpnmjpoangjfff?hl=en-US) extension which gives you an extra tab in `CDT`. The tab will display ALL CSS used for the element you select.